# why getting windowManager$BadTokenException in this code?

Tags: android

```
public class ReviewActivity extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reviewfrag_layout);
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ReviewActivity.this.getSystemService( 
                    LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            ContextThemeWrapper mTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, 
                    R.style.customDialog); 

            mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null); 
            // mDialog = new Dialog(this,0); // context, theme 

            mDialog = new Dialog(mTheme); 
            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
            mDialog.setContentView(this.mView); 

               //if i comment below line  code runs otherwise give exception
           mDialog.show();
        }
}
```

Style:

```
<style name="customDialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Log messages:
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@411eeaa0 is not valid; is your activity running?
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.mds.restau.activity.ReviewActivity$1.onClick(ReviewActivity.java:74)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-10 13:20:01.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

It is context problem. if you are open this activity from the Activity group then instead of using  setContentView(R.layout.xxxx) use following:

View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.XXXX, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);

hope it will works